# can't get #include to work

Tags: c++, header-files, codeblocks

I'm doing the stanford course cs106b in C++, and I'm stuck and I can't seem to get it right. This probably a very easy fix for someone who knows this kind of stuff.
I have three files, one main.cpp and a randword.h and randword.cpp. In randword.h I have #include "simpio.h" which is a stanford library where GetLine() is defined. I can get GetLine() to work in the main.cpp file but when I try to compile I get "undefined reference to 'GetLine()'" in randword.cpp.

I use codeblocks and I have used the "Add files..." function.

Here's the code for main.cpp:

```
  #include "randword.h"

  /* Private function prototypes */

  /* Main program */
  randword rw;
  int main() {
  rw.initDictionary();


}
```

randword.h:

```
   #ifndef RANDWORD_H_INCLUDED
   #define RANDWORD_H_INCLUDED

   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <stdio.h>

   #include "simpio.h"
   #include "strutils.h"


   using namespace std;

   class randword{
       public:
       void initDictionary();
       string chooseRandomWord();
       string strArray[];
       private:

   };


   #endif // RANDWORD_H_INCLUDED
```

random.cpp:

```
   #include "randword.h"

   using namespace std;

   void randword::initDictionary(){
       string fileName;
       ifstream infile;
       fileName = GetLine();
       infile.open(fileName.c_str());
       if(infile.fail()) cout << "Couldn't read file.";
       return;
   }

   string randword::chooseRandomWord(){
   string st1;
   return st1;

   }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I suspect that this question was already posted, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: is `simpio.h` in the same directory as these files?

Comment: you need to *link* your prebuilt Stanford library which contains the function. I don't use CodeBlocks, but there should be an option to add a library to the build - follow that...

Comment: The `#include` pattern looks right, but when you link the object files together, the linker can't find the *definition* of `GetLine()`, which will be in some object file (`simpio.o`?) or library (`cs106b.so`?) supplied with the course. If the build process isn't described in your course material, ask the instructor.

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker error (i.e. unrelated to `#include`). If it works in `main.cpp` but fails in `randword.cpp`, then it's probably trying to link them separately (invoking the linker twice instead of linking `main.o`, `randword.o`, and `simpio.o` all together). I don't know how to configure CodeBlocks, though.

Comment: does randword.cpp include "randword.h" correctly?, I cant see the randword.cpp file in the ones you posted (unless random.cpp is randword.cpp) and you miss typed it :).

Comment: Can you provide your compilation and linking commands?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the library manually using code blocks

- Open up your project
- Right click your project and select build options..
- select debugger
- Go to linker settings
- Under Link Librarys click "add"
- Find your lib file, select it and keep as a relative path
- Your project SHOULD run, if not reply here(as i explained something wrong)

---

randword.cpp does NOT have the library file needed to use `GetLine`, you may have included it inside your header file, but this does not carry over to randword.cpp. You need to include the library file just as you would in any other file in order to have access to it's functions.

```
//randword.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "simpio.h" //include again!!!

//code here....
```

Comment: I added the simpo.cpp file to the project and now it works! Thanks for your help!